# The way to import any Stock Exchange Stock data to Google Sheets, if someone will BE ABLE TO FIGURE OUT THE IMPORT XML CODE HERE!

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Somebody, please write an IMPORTXML formula to get this price out of google search...

Google search link is https://www.google.com/search?q=

And if you ask it for the stock price with ticker like that https://www.google.com/search?q=ticker+096530

it will almost always get you the one you need

so the example link is https://www.google.com/search?q=ticker+096530

Please help to get the price from it. Thank You.

[image: Google search example]

Comment: Kirill, Вы, видимо, хотели задать Ваш вопрос на stackoverflow.com, а не на ru.stackoverflow.com. Здесь вопросы принято задавать на русском, так что Ваш скоро закроют

Comment: Понял, спасибо за уведомление... Я думал stackoverflow единый)